# Apply function to list of lists - Python

Tags: python, pandas, function, apply

I'm aiming to pass a list of lists to a function iteratively but I'm returning an error. The code below creates a random list of lists. Once generated, it gets passed to a separate function.

So the list of lists is named `mult_samples`. I'm hoping to pass this to a function.

But I can't pass the whole list of lists. How can I iterate over all sublists and return the output as an array or df?

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({                    
        'X' : [1.0,3.0,2.0,2.0,4.0,3.0,3.0,4.0,4.0],
    })

def randomSamples():

    A = df['X']

    n = len(df['X'])

    maxv = int(A.max())
    minv = int(A.min())

    one_sample = []

    for x in range(0, n):

        one_sample.append(random.randint(minv, maxv))

    samples = [one_sample for _ in range(10)]

    return samples

mult_samples = randomSamples()
```

Subset out list1 and list2

Out:

```
mult_samples[0] = [3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3]

mult_samples[1] = [1, 4, 1, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2]

def func(U, m = 2, r = 0.2):

    def _maxdist(x_i, x_j):
        return max([abs(ua - va) for ua, va in zip(x_i, x_j)])

    def _phi(m):
        x = [[U[j] for j in range(i, i + m - 1 + 1)] for i in range(N - m + 1)]
        C = [len([1 for x_j in x if _maxdist(x_i, x_j) <= r]) / (N - m + 1.0) for x_i in x]
        return (N - m + 1.0)**(-1) * sum(np.log(C))

    N = len(U)

    return abs(_phi(m + 1) - _phi(m))

output_mult_samples = func(mult_samples)

#output_mult_samples = list(map(funclist, mult_samples))

print(output_mult_samples)
```

Out

```
mult_samples[0] = 0.253692959177
mult_samples[1] = 0.0397554025155
```

Comment: Can you please be little more clear

Comment: @Jeril, how about now?

Comment: Can you give more information about `func`? What is the nature of parameters? What did you expect to happen and what happened instead?

Comment: what does `func` do? can you share its code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I infer from your question, assuming you want to apply `func` to every list inside your list, you can proceed like this :

```
# apply the function 'func' to every LIST inside the main list
output_mult_samples = list(map(func, mult_samples))
```

EDIT: After getting `func` definition in question, you need only map that to the list of lists.

Also, you need to fix the function `randomSamples`. All you are doing as of now is putting the same `one_sample` list 10 times in  your `samples`. You should do something like this instead:

```
samples = []

for _ in range(10):
    one_sample = []
    for x in range(0, n):
        one_sample.append(random.randint(minv, maxv))
    samples.append(one_sample)
```

Comment: Thanks @Jarvis. I've included the function. I think I need to change the datatype.

Comment: I've updated the question @Jarvis. I'm actually drawing an error with the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Jarvis. This is now returning values but it seems to be using a single list still.  I am export 10 random lists to the secondary function, which should return 10 different values. But they are all identical? Does that make sense?

Comment: That's because your `mult_samples` is not really random. Try printing that and you will find that all the lists inside this list are the SAME. @jonboy

Comment: Did you check if the lists in `mult_samples` are same or not? I don't think they are and I provided the fix in my updated answer. @jonboy

Comment: Apologies. You are right. My mistake. Thanks for you help

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of options about how you want to handle the data. An example of how to loop through nested lists is below.

```
for i in range(len(mult_samples)):
    print('Here we are in a list: ' + str(mult_samples[i]))
    for j in range(len(mult_samples[i])):
        print('Access location ' + str(j) + 'in list ' + str(i) + ': ' + str(mult_samples[i][j]))
```

To make a list into an array `np.array(some list)`.

To make a python dictionary into a data frame `pd.DataFrame(some dict)`.